# EventBus: How to keep track?

Tags: android, event-bus, otto, greenrobot-eventbus

I am using an [event bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) (greenrobot) for communication between fragments and activities. 
Works great.

But one thing I was wondering about: How do people keep track of where these are fired?

Example: When I see an `onEvent()` method somewhere, how can I find the places where this gets fired?

Answer (score 3):

Granted you are using IntelliJ Idea/Android Studio, and the method is `onEvent*(E ...)`:

- Ctrl + click on `E` will move you to `E` class file
- Ctrl + click again on `E` class (as in e.g. `public class`**E**) will show you all the usages of `E` class in general. You may want to filter out import statements in the show pop out dialog by clicking on the *italized*, blue ***i*** icon.

Bonus:
If the event class has only one constructor, it's better to ctrl + click it instead of class name. This will show you places where the event object is created.

Comment: Problem (for me) is that my `onEvent(E...)` methods do not always follow the principle that `E...` is the source for the `post`. I do have Fragments that fire an event and pass just a data object as the parameter... In these cases this does not work...